# Problem Adding javascript object to array via a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem with my `carPassing` function. I'm trying to add a object literate into an array. Console log is a number instead of an array list. Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

If the array is too big, does it just give the sum instead?

obtained:

`4`

expected:

```
[
  {
    time: 1568329654807,
    speed: 40,
  },
  {
    time: 1568329821632,
    speed: 42,
  },
  {
    time: 1568331115463,
    speed: 35
  },

  {
    time: 1568331115463,
    speed: 38
  }
]
```

Tried: Quick Google, `splicing`, alternative inputs, `printing` separately and `unshift`.

Code:

```
const carPassing = function(cars, speed){
  return cars.push({time: Date.now(), speed: speed});
}

const cars = [
  {
    time: 1568329654807,
    speed: 40,
  },
  {
    time: 1568329821632,
    speed: 42,
  },
  {
    time: 1568331115463,
    speed: 35
  }
]

const speed = 38

console.log(carPassing(cars, speed));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the array [`.push() docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The `push()` method adds zero or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

and as in your code you are simply returning

```
return cars.push({time: Date.now(), speed: speed});
```

It is actually doing the same. If you wan to get the updated array list, you can simply return the array instead of `push` result like:

```
const carPassing = function(cars, speed){
  cars.push({time: Date.now(), speed: speed});
  return cars;
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
const carPassing = function(cars, speed){
  cars.push({time: Date.now(), speed: speed});
  return cars
}

const cars = [
  {
    time: 1568329654807,
    speed: 40,
  },
  {
    time: 1568329821632,
    speed: 42,
  },
  {
    time: 1568331115463,
    speed: 35
  }
]

const speed = 38
console.log(carPassing(cars, speed));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```